# iFrame not scrollable when height is not 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, iframe

I have two iFrames, one is the content (this has nothing to do), but the one is driving me nuts is a vertical menu than displays several options to the user.

Everytime the vertical menu (let's call it ***vmenu***) shows up I calculate its height depending on how many options the menu will display, and if the resultant height is greater than `window.innerHeight`, vmenu's height is set to that window.innerHeight.

But then it won't be scrollable. Instead, if I set its height to 100% it will be scrollable but will extend to the whole page (background page) which makes it scrollable too (two scrollable frames, awful).

What I only want is to set vmenu's height to `window.innerHeight` and to be scrollable without affecting whole page.

I have already set `overflow-y: scroll` and also tried setting scrolling attribute to 'yes' and force it, but nothing.

My iframe code:

```
<iframe 
    id="iFrameVMenu" 
    name="iFrameVMenu" 
    frameborder="0" 
    style="width: 0%; height: 100%; position: absolute; right: 0px; visibility: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;" 
    scrolling="auto" 
    src='<%= request.getContextPath() + "/.../.../.../layout.jsp" %>' 
    onmouseout="...">
```

If it helps, these two iframes I mention (only one matters now) are in a JSP page.

I would appreciate any idea on how to get this to work properly.

Thanks.

Comment: first of all, try to remove your inline styling for best practice in coding. second: why `width: 0%`? the iframe will not display in this way! try to set it to `width: 100%` too or similar

Comment: You should supply more code, but my estimated advice would be to wrap the vmenu in a div tag that consistently has its height set to window.innerWidth, while the vmenu retains height: 100% and overflow-y: scroll.